# Google Play Subscription

Tags: google-play-store

I have bought a subscription on some google play app but when I was paying for it I have entered wrong email address that I am using on google play.

Now I cant see my subscription on "my subscriptions" list.
Is there a way to cancel it now?

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to [Cancel or change a subscription on Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7018481?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en-GB)

> **Cancel a subscription**
>
> Uninstalling the app will not cancel your subscription.
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Google Play Store Google Play.
>      2.Check if you’re signed in to the correct Google Account.
> 2. Tap Menu Menuand then Subscriptions.
> 3. Select the subscription you want to cancel.
> 4. Tap Cancel subscription.
> 5. Follow the instructions.
>
> If you have a subscription with an app and the app gets removed from Google Play, your future subscription will be canceled. Your past subscriptions will not be refunded.
>
> **What happens after you cancel**
>
> When you cancel a subscription you’ll still be able to use your subscription for the time you’ve already paid.
>
> For example, if you buy a one-year subscription on Jan. 1 for $10 and decide to cancel your subscription on July 1:
>
> You’ll have access to the subscription until Dec. 31.
>   You won’t be charged another yearly subscription of $10 the following Jan.